# The scan function isn't taking values in... It is just displaying the print function

Tags: c, input, char, printf, scanf

```c
void kmmil()
{

    int x, y;
    printf("a.KM TO MILS\n");
    printf("b.MILS TO KM\n");
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("this is the value %c", c);
}
```

output:

```
this is the value (blank)
```

end;

Comment: There's probably a `\n` left over on the input stream from some other `scanf` call up in whatever code it is that calls `kmmil`.  Try changing `scanf("%c", &c)` to `scanf(" %c", &c)` (note the extra space).

Comment: I bet there is another `scanf()` call in your code somewhere.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]. The problem is most likely in some code you didn't show.

Comment: @alex01011 nope... this function only has one scanf().

Comment: @SteveSummit i got it now thanks... idk why that happened tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scanf "doesn't work" it usually does but not in a way we intended to. If you have another scanf in your code, that for example scans a number. You type in your terminal something like 123 and hit enter to confirm. That enter however stays in the input and waits to be scanned by something. This is probably why your scanf "doesn't work". Onto the solution to that:
I suggest you clear your input. You can do this in at least

```c
scanf("%*[^\n]"); // scan and delete everything until newline character
scanf("%*c"); // scan and delete one more character (newline)
```

or

```c
while(getchar() != '\n'); // get characters until newline (note that newline is deleted this way too!)
```